# How do I make button label translations work in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk, locale, gtk3

I'm trying to make a simple dialog window in GTK 3 where the button labels are set in accordance with the chosen language.

Here is my program `gtklocale.c`:

```
#include <glib/gi18n.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *dialog;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons(
        "Title",
        NULL,
        0,
        _("_Cancel"),
        GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
        _("_OK"),
        GTK_RESPONSE_OK,
        NULL);

    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this program with

```
gcc -Wall -o gtklocale -Wall $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) gtklocale.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0)
```

Here are my locales:

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
sv_SE.utf8
```

When I run the program as

```
LC_ALL=sv_SE.utf8 ./gtklocale
```

this dialog window is displayed:

[image]

I would expect "Cancel" to be translated into the Swedish word "Avbryt" but it isn't.

What is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Here you are using the `_()` macro, i.e. *direct* `g_gettext()`, so the translations must be provided by your application; they will not be searched in libraries domains (libraries .mo files), but only in **your application** domain (that is, your application .mo file)

It's true that Gtk3 provides some 'stock' translated strings for use by applications, but they were deprecated in Gtk *3.10*. From *Gtk 3.10* on, it is recommended that applications provide their own translations of UI strings instead of relying on Gtk provided ones.

To reflect this, the devs updated the documentation for *gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons*: see the docs in [Gtk 3.8](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.8/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-new-with-buttons) and [Gtk 3.10](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-new-with-buttons) and compare. The new docs, simply put, are made to **NOT** make use of Gtk own translations!

Of course you can still make use of Gtk own translations, although deprecated, with one of the following ways:

- Use stock identifiers in place of button labels:

```
dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons(
    "Title", NULL, 0,
    GTK_STOCK_CANCEL,
    GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
    GTK_STOCK_OK,
    GTK_RESPONSE_OK,
    NULL);
```

- Call `g_dgettext()` with **"gtk30"** domain:

```
dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons(
    "Title", NULL, 0,
    g_dgettext("gtk30", "_Cancel"),
    GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
    g_dgettext("gtk30", "_OK"),
    GTK_RESPONSE_OK,
    NULL);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Since we are using GTK, it's better to use `g_dgettext` etc

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions, replacing the call to `gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons` in `gtklocale.c` and recompiling but I get the same result when I invoke `LC_ALL=sv_SE.utf8 ./gtklocale` -- no translation.

Comment: Hi, works for me! :) I get "Avbryt" and "OK". Maybe there's something else going on?

Comment: @lb90 Maybe. Could you post the entire program as a minimal reproducible example? I use a simple window manager (Blackbox) on Debian 10 and login from a console (old style). Could it be that I need to run some additional daemon?

Comment: Hi August, sure! Here's the link: https://gist.github.com/lb90/56a60806914cf7d658558fafe82e8ef5. Should that not work for you, try adding a call to `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` before `gtk_init()`.

Comment: Also consider running locale-gen: https://serverfault.com/questions/54591/how-to-install-change-locale-on-debian. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: @lb90 I have tried your example both with and without `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")`; still no luck. My locale configuration seems to be okay, since invoking the *date* command with `LC_ALL=sv_SE.utf8` and `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8` respectively gives the expected result. Could it be that I need to install some missing GTK translation package?

Comment: Could be. Check if the `usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/gtk30.mo` catalog file is present in your system

Comment: @lb90 Yes, the .mo file is present.

Comment: I really don't know, then - sorry :/